# What returns $id of $models->execute_kw() in API web service of Odoo

Tags: php, odoo, odoo-8

May be this question as same as like others, but I want to know well about this problem. I am new to learn API web service of Odoo for Android.

I have followed this docs https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/api_integration.html and some other docs.

```
<?php
require_once('ripcord-master/ripcord.php');

$url = "http://100.100.1.148:8069";
$db = "UAT_DISTRICT";
$username = "openpg";
$password = "serving";
$info = ripcord::client('https://demo.odoo.com/start')->start();
list($url, $db, $username, $password) = array($info['host'], $info['database'], $info['user'], $info['password']);
$common = ripcord::client("$url/xmlrpc/2/common");
//$common->version();
//Authenticate the credentials
$uid = $common->authenticate($db, $username, $password, array());

$models = ripcord::client("$url/xmlrpc/2/object");

$id = $models->execute_kw($db, $uid, $password, 'res.partner', 'create', array(array('name' => "NEW USER")));
echo "New user has been created, ID: ".$id;
```

Actually, what is actually $id is? As I know $id returns the ID of new user. But why it always returns 51, while my current id in res_partner table is 1559. The 51 has been created a long times ago. Anyone can tell me why? The good answer is appreciated.

Comment: have you checked your db if the users are actually created....also in `res.partner` the email address is a compulsory field that must be filled along with the company of the user (if you are using mutli-company) if not the record won't get created...so address those issues and tell me your findings

Comment: there is no new data inserted in res.partner. I will try to complete the required field now

Comment: I can not fully answer the question, but, the function execute_kw is defined in odoo/service/model.py at line 58 ; you can download the source of Odoo for free (community edition). I have tried to reverse the file, but it's out of my understanding.